# Change String in Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

This looks like the simplest runnable I could imagine

```
public class StringShower implements Runnable{

    private volatile boolean running = true;
    private String text;

    public StringShower(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Current text" + text);
                if(text != null){
                    showText(text); 
                }
                Thread.sleep((long) 1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                running = false;
            }
        }       
    }

    private void showText(String text2) {
        System.out.println("Current Text " + text2);

    }
    public void stopRunning() {
        this.running = false;
    }
```

That is the class starting it

```
public class ChangeString {

  private static String changeme;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Thread thread1 = new Thread(new StringShower(changeme));
      thread1.start();

      changeme = "changed";
  }
}
```

After reading many examples, I can't still figure out why the `String` inside the thread is never updated. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`changeme = "changed";` changes what `String` `changeme` references in the main method, it does not change what reference `text` in your `StringShower` instance is referencing.

Since a `String` is also immutable and cannot be changed, you could wrap the string with another class that gets and sets a `String`, and pass a reference of this wrapper class.

If you do make such a wrapper class, make sure the get and set are synchronized so that each thread sees what the latest reference refers to when querying.

Comment: tried the other suggestions also but putting the string to a wrapper class actually did work straightforward. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what NESPowerGlove  said.  String is Immutable.  You can never change the value of the string.  Whenever you try to update it or set it to something you are either creating a new object or just referencing an existing string.

Answer (score 0):

`StringShower` holds a reference to `null` in its `text` field. How?

`changeMe` is initialized to `null` by default and that's what you're passing to `StringShower` and assigning to `text`. You then update the reference that `changeMe` points to, but this has no effect on what `text` points to (which is still `null`).

If you want to manipulate the `text` field, consider using a setter. And / or make sure the text you pass to the `StringShower` constructor has been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `text`  with the value of a reference which points to the same object as `changeme` does. Later you change the reference saved in `changeme` but this does not affect `text` because you did not change the object they point to but saved a new reference in `changeme`.

Java is pass-by-value. See [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value]) for a more in-depth explanation.